# Where is the "Send to Archive" option in High Sierra

Tags: finder, high-sierra, archive, zip

I have recently updated to Mac OS X High Sierra and noticed that there is no longer a archive or compress option in the context menu in finder.

Has this feature been removed or is a there a setting to enable to use this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be in the same place still (and it is also in the File menu):

[image]

Comment: Ok I see whats going on here, it seems that if you search for files in finder. You cant select them and choose to s "Compress" them, in a normal finder window it works fine.

Comment: I also get the "... komprimieren" entry for files in a search result...